# Finding $\liminf\limits_{ r \to 1^{-}}$ and $\limsup\limits_{ r \to 1^{-}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k r^{2^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

In an answer last year to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2494542/does-zz2z4z8-ever-become-unboundedly-negative), I implicitly asserted as an aside that that $\lim\limits_{r \to 1^-} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k r^{2^k}$ seemed empirically to be close to $\frac12$.  I now think that there is not a limit, but that there are a limit inferior and a limit superior.  So my question here is about finding $$\liminf\limits_{ r \to 1^{-}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k r^{2^k} \text { and }\limsup\limits_{ r \to 1^{-}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k r^{2^k}$$

Empirically, I now think

- the limit inferior seems to be about $0.497250779$ and approached when $r$ is close to $1-\frac{0.6982}{2^{2n}}$ for increasing integers $n$
- the limit superior seems to be about $0.502749221$ and approached when $r$ is close to $1-\frac{0.6982}{2^{2n+1}}$ for increasing integers $n$

If it helps, the terms of the series can be made positive with $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k r^{2^k} = \sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty} r^{4^m}\left(1-r^{4^m}\right)$

Is there an analytical method for finding these values?

Comment: At least partly answered [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198665/on-an-example-of-an-eventually-oscillating-function).

Comment: @DanielFischer - that is helpful, suggesting that the $0.502749221$ and $0.497250779$ are close to $\dfrac12 \pm \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\log_e(2)\sinh{\left(\pi^2/\log_e(2)\right)}}}$